# Cypress.moment() is not a function on upgrading Cypress version to 9.6

Tags: cypress

Few test cases in my test suite is failing because I am using Cypress.moment() function in those

I tried one of the solution mentioned online to upgrade code coverage : npm update @cypress/code-coverage but this did not solved the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Cypress deprecated `Cypress.moment()` in 6.1.0,](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/changelog#6-1-0) because [Moment.js was considered legacy](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/8714).

Cypress recommends [using one of `Moment.js`'s suggested alternatives](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/-project-status/recommendations/) instead of `Cypress.moment()`.

Answer (score 2):

I used [Day.js](https://day.js.org/docs/en/query/is-a-dayjs) instead of using `Cypress.moment()`, and it worked.

**Steps:**

1 Install the package by running the command: `npm install dayjs`

2 Add `import dayjs from "dayjs"` at the top of the test

3 Use `dayjs()` method, for example: `const nowTime = dayjs().format('H:m:s')`